# One-To-Many Relationship with Join Table

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have a one-to-many relationship modeled using join table:

```
create table t1 (id int primary key, name varchar(10) /*...*/);
create table t2 (id int primary key, name varchar(10) /*...*/);
create table t1_t2 (t1_id int, t2_id int, primary key (t1, t2));
```

The tables are supposed to model the relationship of one t1 to many t2. What is the right way to model these tables using JPA?

Comment: I think you can find what you are looking for at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_using_a_JoinTable_database

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The typical table for one T1 to many T2 is to have a foreign key on T2 pointing toward T1. The T1_T2 table is usually not needed.

The JPA structure would then be a One-To-Many, possibly two-way.

---

There could be some arrangements, to make the structure you describe work. You could change T1_T2:

- add a unique constraint on T2 (so that only one T2 is allowed)

Is that really what you want?

**Edited**: yes, it is what you want ;-)

I doubt you may find many examples on the net. I have no proved solution, but I would try something along these lines:

In [Hibernate annotation reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections), see "2.2.5.3.2.3. Unidirectional with join table" to get the idea. It looks like:

```
    @Entity
    public class Trainer {
        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(
            name="TrainedMonkeys",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="trainer_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="monkey_id")
        )
        public Set<Monkey> getTrainedMonkeys() {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's true that mine is not the most typical structure, but I have other reasons that make it more suitable. The unique constraint on T2 is possible, but I still don't get how I should model it using JPA annotations. Could you please explain further?

Comment: OK. I'm curious of what could makes this design "more suitable" though. Could you give some hints, to improve my knowledge in case I need this in the future?

Comment: Thank you. That's really informative. As for the design, when the number of records in T2 which are actually related to T1 is relatively small, you may opt to having a separate join table rather than having a `t1_id` in T2 that is mostly `NULL`.

Comment: Excellent justification. Thanks for sharing ;-) I'll give you my vote !

Comment: I have a case where keeping the join table is not just more suitable, but mandatory.  When the child entity can be the 1:M child of multiple types of parent entities.  In that case you cannot have the fk column in the child entity and must go with a join table.

Comment: HDave is correct - it is a very common pattern to have intermediary tables and not always a direct relationship. Consider Cars and Owners or any other example. A Car coming off the assembly line may have a VIN but not an Owner but if there is one there is only one. In such a case, there would be both Owner and Car tables plus an Owner_Car table that shows what Cars a given Owner has (which may be many). There is no direct FK from Car to Owner. JPA makes this painfully difficult (IMHO) perhaps due to an over-simplified set of cases it was originally designed to solve.

Comment: A real scenario could be a document class entity, where documents could be related in many other entities, and keep all relationships manage from the others. I hope this could be clarifier to others.