# Hibernate - implement one-to-many relationship as many to many

Tags: hibernate

I recently appeared for an interview and interviewer asked me that if there are two objects - Body and parts, relation is one to many between body and parts.He asked why would we implement one to many relation as **many to many** when it comes to Hibernate?

I do not know if that's true.If its true, why do we do that?

Comment: We wouldn't, otherwise it would be a many-to-many association, and not a one-to-many association anymore. This question doesn't make much sense. If the question was "why would we use a join table instead of a join column to map a one-to-many association", then it would start making sense.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, that means it was a trap, found answer for the second one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378248/one-to-many-relationship-with-join-table