# JPA Unidirectional @OnetoMany fails

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, one-to-many

I have couple of failure cases for Unidirectional JPA2 @OnetoMany relationship 
below is the code snippet

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

       @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName="CUSTOMER_ID")
       private List<Address> customerAddresses;

....
}
```

In this case it fails to create Entity manager factory during server startup with the following error

```
DEBUG - Second pass for collection: xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.core.domainmodel.customerinfo.Customer.customerAddresses
 DEBUG - Binding a OneToMany: xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.core.domainmodel.customerinfo.Customer.customerAddresses through a foreign key
 DEBUG - Mapping collection: xx.xxx.xxxxxxx.core.domainmodel.customerinfo.Customer.customerAddresses -> CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
 DEBUG - Unable to build entity manager factory
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1456) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar:4.3.6.Final]
```

The server startup is all good when I remove the `referencedColumnName` attribute from the `@JoinColumn` annotation

But when I try to persist the entity it fails below are the Hibernate generated traces for the failure(`CUSTOMER_ID is the name of the identity generated PK column in CUSTOMER table and FK in the CUSTOMER_ADDRESS table`)

```
DEBUG - Executing identity-insert immediately
DEBUG - insert into CUSTOMER (ESTABLISHMENT_DATE, ESTABLISHMENT_PLACE, MAJOR_PRODUCT, PAID_UP_CAPITAL, TYPE_OF_BUSINESS, COMPANY_REGISTRATION_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_TYPE, FAX_NUMBER, ID_EXPIRY_DATE, ID_ISSUE_DATE, ID_ISSUE_PLACE, ID_NUMBER, ID_TYPE, TELEPHONE_NO, ENGLISH_NAME, RACE, NATIONALITY, MALAY_NAME) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG - Natively generated identity: 6
DEBUG - Executing identity-insert immediately
DEBUG - insert into CUSTOMER_ADDRESS (COUNTRY, ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, ADDRESS_LINE3, ADDRESS_LINE4, PINCODE, STATE, ADDRESS_TYPE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG - could not execute statement [n/a]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CUSTOMER_ID', table 'xxxxxxx.xxx.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

What is the reason for failure in the first case, and how to get it to work either way, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that your annotation @JoinColumn with "name" and "referencedColumnName" is fine? Example:

name: If the join is for a unidirectional OneToMany mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy, the foreign key is in the table of the target entity.

referencedColumnName: When used with a unidirectional OneToMany foreign key mapping, the referenced column is in the table of the source entity.

Comment: If you really want to have a _unidirectional_ `OneToMany` mapping, you shoud check [One-To-Many Relationship with Join Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378248/one-to-many-relationship-with-join-table).

Comment: @Mário Kapusta: The foreignkey is in the target entity while I placed the Joincolumn in the source entity here. Since I want to retreive address only from Customer entity not and as a stand alone data, in which case it may not have any value as a data. So as per your comment JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName="CUSTOMER_ID")
       private List<Address> customerAddresses; is supposed to cause an error in this case?

Comment: hello(sorry that i am so late)...answer: yes...you should have "referencedColumnName" - column of source entity ,,,,, "name" - fk in target entity. In your case it seems like bug is here.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. Adding `@JoinColumn(nullable = false, ...)` fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me :)

Comment: Even this fixed for me, but what did it do to fix it? What is the meaning of this configuration.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal - *(optional) Whether the foreign key column is nullable* - is sated in the documentation for the attribute `nullable`. if you constrain the foreign key to **not null**, you must specify `@JoinColumn(nullable = false)`. Otherwise it is not needed.

Answer (score -2):

Probably the links below could give you more information on oneToMany relationship.

It indicates to use mappedBy at parent side and use JoinColumn at childs.

[JPA JoinColumn vs mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby)

Comment: He is talking about an _unidirectional_ link. In that case it makes no sense to use a `mappedBy` - because that one is used in _bidirectional_ links.

Comment: My apologies; I just missed Unidirectional part. Thanks for pointing that out.