# How to tell JPA to manage dependent entities?

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

My model has a typical parent-children-relation which is JPA-modelled by an unidirectional `@OneToMany` relation:
a `Parent` has 0..n instances of `Child` (i.e. a `List<Child>`).

Trying to create and persist an `Entity` with one dependent `Property` as follows:

```
val a_parent = Parent(
        id = "I_am_a_parent",
        children = listOf(Child(kind="childish"))
)
parentRepository.save(a_parent)
```

surprisingly results in

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [parent_id]; nested exception is 
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: null value in column "parent_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (22, childish, null).
```

at the line `parentRepository.save(a_parent)`.

Obviously, JPA does not set the id of the parent on the child (column `children.parent_id`).

**Why not? And how to tell it to do so?**

The code of `Parent` and `Child` is as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
data class Parent (
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        var id: String? = null,

        @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
        var properties: List<Child> = listOf()
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
data class Child (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Int? = null,

        @Column(name = "kind")
        var kind: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Why do you use nullable `@Id` columns?

Comment: @AlexRudenko The column is not nullable, the property is. Because JPA expects a default parameterless constructor. Kotlin generates the parameterless constructor from the default values. I could take 0 or -1 for the default parameter but I prefer `null` as `null` is not a valid value for an id. - But this topic has nothing to do with the error and the problem of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unidirectional OneToMany may have to be implemented this way ([reference](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)):

```kotlin
data class Parent (
  //...
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    var properties: List<Child> = listOf()
)
```

Pay attention to `nullable = false` if the database column `parent_id` is not nullable.

Comment: You are proposing a bidirectional relation. There are many different ways to implement a parent-children-relationship. I need a unidirectional relation.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that requirement.
Thus, your implementation seems to be quite valid - as described in reference [like this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)  However, in such case, the column `parent_id` must be nullable :-\

Comment: That was the right hint. The column `parent_id` doesn't need to be nullable. But if it's not, then a `nullable=false` in my `@JoinColumn` is needed (like given in your answer). So, feel free to edit your answer according to a unidirectional relation and I will vote it up and accept it.

Comment: Yep. similar issue [had happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811989/jpa-unidirectional-onetomany-fails)